# Trigger an event using user Control C#

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

Suppose If I have a button on a custom made user control that removes the control from the form (Lets call it formX) it is placed in.

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ParentForm.Controls.Remove(this);
}
```

Now upon closing this UserControl I want a method in the formX to be called.

I tried doing something like this :

```
discount.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(discount_ControlRemoved);

void UserControl_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    CallMethod();
}
```

However this does not work, when removing the userControl from formX the event is not even called in the debugger.

How do I do this?

Comment: The ControlRemoved event fires for controls being removed from the event holder, in this case controls being removed from the `discount` instance.

Comment: The ControlRmoved you wrote is on the UserControl, meaning that it will only fire if you remove a control from your UserControl. You need to either listen to ControlRemoved on the parent control (in your case the form) or raise an event in the user control that the parent form will listen to.

Comment: I would make the UserControl raise a Custom Event that the Form subscribes to.  The Event could pass a reference to the UserControl out.  Then the Form can retrieve state information from the UserControl if necessary and then remove the control itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you should be using is the `ControlRemoved` event on the parent container, likely the `Form` in this case. You could do this several ways, some may be better than others depending upon what all you want to do, but the following should at least do what you are requesting:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(Form1_ControlRemoved);
    }

    void Form1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control.Name == "NameOfUserControl") CallMethod();
    }

    private void CallMethod()
    {
        // Do stufff...
    }
}
```

This assumes that you have named your `User Control` instance "NameOfUserControl". There are various ways you could check for the control being removed to be the correct one. You can also make this a bit more dynamic by doing this in the control itself while using delegates to call back to the parent form, etc... This is just a basic example.